# How to search urls that are not in any html tag and then turn them into hyperlinks?

Tags: php, regex, url

So my problem is that, in the same content there are iframes, image tags and etc. They all have regex matches that will convert them into the correct format.

The last thing left is the normal URL. I need a regex, that will find all links that are simply links and not inside of a iframe, img or any other tag. Tags used in this case are regular HTML tags and not BB.

Currently I got this code as the last pass of the content rendering. But it will also react to all the other things done above (iframes and img renderings.) So it goes and swaps the urls out there aswell.

```
$output = preg_replace(array(
    '%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s'
), array(
    'test'
), $output);
```

And my content looks something like this:

```
# dont want these to be touched
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://somedomain.com/but-still-its-a-link-to-somewhere/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<img src="http://someotherdomain.com/here-is-a-img-url.jpg" border="0" />

# and only these converted
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
https://www2.google.com<br />
www.google.com
```

As you can see, there also might be something at the end of the link. After a full day of trying regexes to work, that last `<br />` has been a nightmare for me.

Comment: I don't think regex is the solution to your problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Description

This solution will match the urls which are not inside tag attribute values, and will replace them with something new.

The regular expression matches both the things you skipped over and the things you replaced. Then the preg_match_callback executes an internal function which tests to see if capture group 1 is populated (this is the desired text) and if so returns the change, otherwise it simply returns the undesired text.

I used your url matching regex with some minor modifications like converting the unused capture groups `(`...`)` to non-capture groups `(?:`...`)`. This makes the regex engine run faster and makes it easier to modify the expression.

The raw expression: `<(?:[^'">=]*|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>|((?:[\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|(?:[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)))`

[image]

## Example

**Code**

```
<?php

$string = '# dont want these to be touched
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://somedomain.com/but-still-its-a-link-to-somewhere/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<img src="http://someotherdomain.com/here-is-a-img-url.jpg" border="0" />

# and only these converted
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
https://www2.google.com<br />
www.google.com';


    $regex = '/<(?:[^\'">=]*|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*>|((?:[\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|(?:[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)))/ims';

    $output = preg_replace_callback(
        $regex,
        function ($matches) {
            if (array_key_exists (1, $matches)) {
                return '<a href="' . $matches[1] . '">' . $matches[1] . '<\/a>';
            }
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $string
    );
    echo $output;
```

**Output**

```
# dont want these to be touched
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://somedomain.com/but-still-its-a-link-to-somewhere/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<img src="http://someotherdomain.com/here-is-a-img-url.jpg" border="0" />

# and only these converted
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com<\/a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com<\/a>
<a href="https://www2.google.com">https://www2.google.com<\/a><br />
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com<\/a>
```

Comment: Amazing answer. But is currently giving me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Well for me it is giving an error because of the callback (im using 5.2.17 ver). And also, if i simply use regex part in my own code, it removes everything from iframes as well.

Comment: That is correct, the regex will match the stuff you want skipped and will match the stuff you want replaced. The stuff to be replaced is placed into capture group 1. Then inside the function it checks to see if capture group 1 is populated. If you place that regex without the function then you're going to have everything replaced.

Comment: preg_replace_callback was added to PHP in 5.3.0 which is now end of life, and the latest version is 5.5.1

Comment: Ok so basically, using callback is only way. Since http://ideone.com/n5txzv this clearly doesnt work.. I tested this in another server and it worked. So basically, the problem is local. I will now go have a friendly chat with the ISP. Thanks man!:)

Comment: Oh man! I'd love to be there to hear that conversation :)  best of luck.

Comment: I'm trying to make it also search for any url which has underscore at the end, such as: `https://twitter.com/testtesttesttest_`. Here is my modification (to the last non-capturing parenthesis): `'/<(?:[^\'">=]*|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*>|((?:[\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|(?:[^[:punct:]\s]|\/|_)))/ims'`. It is working for me, but I'm not sure if it is safe to use. Kindly help check. Thanks.

Comment: @IanY. Yes your modification will work to identify embedded strings that end in an underbar. However I'd make a slight change.  Your `[^[:punct:]\s]|\/|_` uses alternation to say "all non punctuation", and all `/`, and all `_`. I'd rewrite that to: `[^[:punct:]\s]|[\/_]` which says "all non punctuation" and any characters like these `/_`. This would make it a bit more efficient, by reducing backtracking, and if in the future you find another character you wanted included it would be easier to add. See also [link](https://regex101.com/r/7IFolm/1)