# How to search image urls that are not inside [img] bb tag and then include these tags using regex & PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

There are many similar topics this one was very close by @Denomales
[How to search urls that are not in any html tag and then turn them into hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764778/how-to-search-urls-that-are-not-in-any-html-tag-and-then-turn-them-into-hyperlin)

But I'm facing slightly diffrent senario

In a text field I have Images enclosed within [IMG] [/IMG] tag e.g

```
[img]http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg[/img]
```

and there are plain image urls i.e without [IMG] tag e.g

```
http://www.jonco48.com/blog/tongue1.jpg
```

I want to find all plain image urls and include [IMG] tags with them (using preg_replace or similar fucntion) so that above url become

```
[img]http://www.jonco48.com/blog/tongue1.jpg[img]
```

Now the real challenge is the statement should skip those image URLS which are already enclosed within [img] bb tag, So how Can I do this my regex understanding is very poor
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you using substitution.

```
((\[img\])?(http:.*?\.(jpg|png|gif))(\[\/img\])?)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aR1fT9/6)

Note: change the inner part to validate URL as well if needed.

sample code:

```
$re = "/((\\[img\\])?(http:.*?\\.(jpg|png|gif))(\\[\\/img\\])?)/i";
$str = "[img]http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg[/img] http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg";
$subst = '[img]$3[/img]';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: and if i need to check other types then regex should look like this 
"/((\\[img\\])?(http:.*?\\.(jpg|png|gif))(\\[\\/img\\])?)/i";
right???

Comment: what does this statement means $subst = '[img]$3[/img]'; and what is $3

Comment: $3 is captured group at index 3 and [img] tag is added around this matched group. Look in demo at right side for matches.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
(?<!\[img\])(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[\w.]+\.[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/\w+)*(?:\.\w+)?)(?!\[\/img\])
```

Replacement:

```
[img]\1[/img]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/44)

Comment: Thanks it also worked but what is the diffrence betwean yours and above answer your looks more complex